# Best tools for preparing and styling a table

Tags: shortcode, table

What are the best tools for preparing and styling a table in Wordpress easily?

Update:

I want to prepare and publish the tables in any page or post. So I think it might be easier if they can be prepared with an easy to use shortcode.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? In what context will this table be used? In the Post Content editor (visual/HTML)? In a template file? In a Widget?

Answer (score 2):

[WP-Table Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/) is a great plugin which allows you to create tables and use their shortcodes in your post. Bear in mind, however, that not all themes are "table-friendly".

Alternatively, you can try [Dean's FCKeditor Plugin For WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/deans-fckeditor-for-wordpress-plugin/), which appears to have an "Insert Table" function to keep you from messing around with HTML.

And the best option, in my opinion, is to learn a couple of HTML tags to wrap your data into tables, and learn a couple of CSS styling rules for those tables. `table`, `tr` and `td` + [CSS Styling Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) tutorial from W3Schools should pretty much get you started without the overhead of plugins and shortcodes. Just my 2c.

Answer (score 0):

[TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) gives you the option to add table-related buttons to the WYSIWYG area. Not extremely powerful, but it gets the job done.